# GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, gulp, minify, gulp-uglify

I have a problem with **uglify** main **bundle.js** file.

This is my **gulp** scripts:

```
gulp.task("compile", () => {
    let tsResult = gulp.src("app/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject());
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(".", { sourceRoot: '/app' }))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/_Dist/'));
});

gulp.task("minify", ["compile"], function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/_Dist/bundle.js'])
        .pipe(concat('bundle.min.js'))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputLocation));
});
```

After running this scripts I catch next exception:

> [15:16:20] [Error] GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript Caused
>   by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (:) File:
>   C:\Projects\AngGulpApp\app\_Dist\bundle.min.js Line: 1

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "gulpfile.ts",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem.
Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to resolve this issue. Basically **uglify** doesn't work with **ES6** (right now just with **ES5**). For resolving this problem we need to **Transpilation** result to **ES5** with TypeScript help, and then run minification.

For example:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');
....
.pipe(ts({
    target: "es5",
    allowJs: true,
    module: "commonjs",
    moduleResolution: "node"
}))
.pipe(uglify())
```

This part of code transpilation my current bundle code to ES5 and then run **uglify()** function for minification.